# Boarding flight before 2 hours of visa date

Tags: visas

I have got visa to travel to Germany from 31/05/2015 to 31/12/2015

I have booked flight which starts in on 30th night  9:55pm which will be 2 hours ahead of visa date

Kindly let me know if it is  ok or should I cancel and book for next day.

Comment: What time do you LAND in Germany?

Comment: I will be landing on 31/05/2015 7.25 am